# Jquery: Update only the next span with a specific class

Tags: jquery

html:

```
<p class="fields">
  <select id="parts">
    <option value="10">Ring</option>
    <option value="50">Necklace</option>
    <option value="3">Pendant</option>
  </select>
  <label for="price">Price</label>
  <span class="price"></span>
</p>


function load_part_price_select(id, value) {
$('#' + id ).live('change',function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/parts/' + value + '/price',
      type: 'get',
              context: this,
      dataType: 'script',
      success: function(responseData) {
        $(this).next("span.price").html(responseData);
      }
    }); 
});
};
```

I've tried this way but no success.

The "onchange" is working fine I just need some help to display the value inside the span tag as a content.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@samccone was on the right track, but it's not working for you because the span.price is not the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element after the select#parts element (which I assume is the element you are sending to the load_part_price_select function).

It is one of the [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) though, so try this:

```
$(this).siblings("span.price:first").html(responseData);
```

Or try [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$(this).nextAll("span.price:first").html(responseData);
```

I'm going to assume that 'siblings' is more efficient because it doesn't care if the matched element is before or after 'this' element. But if you don't want to match previous spans, use 'nextAll'.

Then set the ajax context as per samccone's comment:

```
function load_part_price_select(id, value) {
$('#' + id ).live('change',function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/parts/' + value + '/price',
      type: 'get',
      context: this,
      dataType: 'script',
      success: function(responseData) {
        $(this).nextAll("span.price:first").html(responseData);
      }
    }); 
});
};
```

Comment: it is because $(this) is not defined... he just has to set the context so that next will work

Comment: it must be only the next span.price tag because in this document may have one or more.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Within that function he has id to work with, so assuming id='parts' he will still need to use siblings() or nextAll() as next() will fail based on the original post HTML.

Comment: @Kleber what you need then is $(this).nextAll("span.price:first") and set the context as per samccone's comment. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You guys, rocks! it worked like a charm! awesome! thank you! but now the doubt, I should choose only one of you to credit for this :/

Comment: I pasted the final code in case someone needs it too. http://pastebin.com/E7dpHRhs

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).next("span.price").html(responseData);
```

should work just fine

Comment: if you do just an alert(responseData) are you getting the value back? It may be an issue of the request not even completing

Comment: yes, I getting the value correctly, also I can see the value thro firebug

Comment: @kleber S ah ok I see what the issue is.. you need to set the context of the ajax call http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  so that this has something to point to

Comment: Added the context but still not working, I've updated my post to show you what I change.

Comment: @kleber S set context to document.getElementById('#parts')